# How to print a variable in a Tkinter Label using Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I print a variable in GUI label?

1. Should I make it a global variable and place it in textvariable=a ?
2. Could I redirect it somehow to textvariable?
3. Is there any other way?

```
#Simple program to randomly choose a name from a list

from Tkinter import * #imports Tkinter module
import random  #imports random module for choice function
import time #imports time module

l=["Thomas", "Philip", "John", "Adam", "Kate", "Sophie", "Anna"]       #creates a list with 7 items
def pri():  #function that asigns randomly item from l list to     variable a and prints it in CLI
    a = random.choice(l) #HOW CAN I PRINT a variable IN label     textvarible????
    print a     #prints in CLI
    time.sleep(0.5)


root = Tk()                 #this
frame = Frame(root)         #creates
frame.pack()                #GUI frame
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

#GUI button
redbutton = Button(frame, text="Choose name", fg="red", command = pri)
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

#GUI label
var = StringVar()
label = Label(bottomframe, textvariable= var, relief=RAISED )
label.pack( side = BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

l=["Thomas", "Philip", "John", "Adam", "Kate", "Sophie", "Anna"]       #creates a list with 7 items
def pri():  #function that asigns randomly item from l list to     variable a and prints it in CLI
    a = random.choice(l) #HOW CAN I PRINT a variable IN label     textvarible????
    print a     #prints in CLI
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return a


root = Tk()

var = IntVar() # instantiate the IntVar variable class
var.set("Philip")     # set it to 0 as the initial value

# the button command is a lambda expression that calls the set method on the var,
# with the var value (var.get) increased by 1 as the argument
Button(root, text="Choose name", command=lambda: var.set(pri())).pack()

# the label's textvariable is set to the variable class instance
Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: If you have achieved what you wanted can you please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My question is how can I  print a random name from the l list in GUI label instead of CLI. It dosen’t work if I write:  var.set(a) or global a. Any ideas?

Comment: @bodgerandscarper -Have edited my answer. It prints randomly a name from your list

Comment: It works at first but when I press the button it gives error: >>> 
Philip
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: pri() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
>>>

Comment: Can you please elaborate what error are you getting? I am able to get the output without any issues

Comment: Ok. You haven't given the parameter for the function call. 

def pri(l):

Comment: @bodgerandscarper -Have updated the latest code which seems to be working. Exactly what you are looking for. Please accept the answer if you are done

Comment: Excellent!! You're a genius

Comment: :) Can you please accept the answer please, that would be better way of appreciation my answer. Click on the "Tick mark" and upvote it. @bodger